# Rotation in 3D (coordinate system transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, 3d, rotations

How do I rotate a point around point [0,0,0] in 3D. In picture I draw specific situation for illustration.
[image: example]

At first I know point G[x,y,z] and I will tranfer it on axiz Z, where distance to center is size of vector g. Then vectors g and gt forms angle φ. Then I get some point A and i need to rotate it same as I rotated G before. But i dont know how.
I think it could be named as coordinate system transformation.

I heard i should use transform matrix. Could you please give me detailed informations?

Comment: Hint: Read the wikipedia article "Rotation matrix". There is a section about 3D rotations and you can find the three basic rotation matrices for x-, y- and z-rotations there. If you want one single matrix which can rotate around all axes, just multiply the three basic matrices together.

Comment: I dont get how is this rotation (coordinate system transformation) identified. I have angle, but I need something else, needn't I? Plane, I guess.

Comment: You need to know the axis around which you're going to rotate. This is some line passing through $(0,0,0)$, so all you need is a vector parallel to this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @bubba answer is totally fine. Also note that you can compute your rotation axis by taking the cross product of $G$ and $G_t$. Supposing that $G=[x,y,z]$ and $G'=[x',y',z']$, the coordinates of $G\times G_t$ are given by
$$
G\times G_t = [yz'-y'z,\;zx'-z'x,\;xy'-x'y].
$$
Also note, that these guys are the minors of the following matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
*  & *  & * \\
x  & y  & z \\
x' & y' & z' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
taken with "+" or "-" sign as in the Laplace decomposition. This also explains why the vector $G\times G_t$ is perpendicular to both $G$ and $G_t$ while staying linearly independent (hint: put the coordinates of $G$ or $G_t$ in place of the star symbols and see what happens). Good luck!

Comment: G x Gt is not unit vector. On wiki writes it should be. How to convert it to unit vector? I tried it with this numbers:
g(9.88, -0.24 , 2.45), gt(10.182 , 0 , 0),-> angle = 13.98955431° -> g x gt = (0 , 24.9459 , 2.44368)

Comment: Yes, you're right. In fact the length of $v\times u$ is equal to $|u||v|\sin\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between these two vectors (such that $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$). But this is not a problem. You just need to normalize your vector, i.e. divide all coordinates by its length.

Comment: Yes it should work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the axis around which you're going to rotate. This is some line passing through $(0,0,0)$, so all you need is a unit vector parallel to this line. Suppose this unit vector is $\mathbf{u} = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$. Then you plug this vector and your angle $\theta$ into the formula given on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to get the rotation matrix.

To rotate any given point, you just multiply its coordinates by this rotation matrix.